# Data Table for react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

Can somebody please suggest any data table component for  react native which can add rows dynamically and having editable cells. I am done searching in google. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the package  available for **React Native data table**

https://github.com/sussol/react-native-data-table

[A React Native data table written purely in JSX with React. ## Installation npm install --save react-native-data-table ## Usage react-native-data-table provides a number of components for constructing a table through composition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6lMQ.png)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

I introduced my own module for this feature from which you will be able to select row easily and much more.

[image: How it's look like]
[image]
[image]

You can use this component like this below

```js
import DataTable, {COL_TYPES} from 'react-native-datatable-component';
    
const SomeCom = () => {

     //You can pass COL_TYPES.CHECK_BOX Column's value in true/false, by default it will be false means checkBox will be uncheck!
     
     const data = [
           { menu: 'Chicken Biryani', select: false }, //If user select this row then this whole object will return to you with select true in this case
           { menu: 'Chiken koofta', select: true },
           { menu: 'Chicken sharwma', select: false }
     ]
     
     const nameOfCols = ['menu', 'select'];
     
     return(
          <DataTable
               onRowSelect={(row) => {console.log('ROW => ',row)}}
               data={data}
               colNames={nameOfCols}
               colSettings={[{name: 'select', type: COL_TYPES.CHECK_BOX}]}
          />
     )
}

export default SomeCom;
```

[React Native DataTable Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-datatable-component)

Comment: This Works! How to add a custom column name.

Comment: @MerrinK there's a prop with the name colNames which accepts array, just passed to it your column name.